# Automaton for prefix matching

Tags: java, finite-automata, nfa, automaton, finite-state-automaton

Using an open source Java automaton library, eg: org.apache.lucene.util.automaton or dk.brics.automaton, how can I build an automaton for prefix matching?

eg: an automaton created from the set of strings ["lucene", "lucid"],  that will match when given "luc", or "luce", but not match when given "lucy" or "lucid dream".

Comment: This is exactly how a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) works. A similar idea can be used to construct the automaton. Usage of an "end of input" character might be useful as well - such as `$`.

Comment: I'm familiar with tries, although the implementations I've found in Java (eg: PatriciaTrie) are actually Maps, and will return a value associated with a prefix. I just want to check for the presence of a prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefix matching is possible using org.apache.lucene.util.automaton by setting all states to accept, eg:

```
    String[] strings = new String[]{"lucene", "lucid dream"};
    final List<BytesRef> terms = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String s : strings) {
        terms.add(new BytesRef(s));
    }
    Collections.sort(terms);
    final Automaton a = DaciukMihovAutomatonBuilder.build(terms);

    for (int i = 0; i < a.getNumStates(); i++) {
        a.setAccept(i, true);
    }
```

Comment: Could you complete the example with the code that tests a string against the such created Automaton? I cannot find any examples with the `DaciukMihovAutomatonBuilder`