# How to check a string against a possible large collection of prefixes and suffixes in Lucene?

Tags: lucene, finite-automata, prefix-tree

I have to implement a function that trims prefixes from a given string. The list of prefixes could be very large so it will be costly to try regular Scala functions [stripPrefix](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/collection/immutable/StringLike.html#stripPrefix(prefix:String):String) one after the other. So I've turned to Lucene in order to create a FSA that will be smaller and more efficient testing for prefixes.

Following this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176474/automaton-for-prefix-matching) I discovered that the automaton I was looking for is the [DaciukMihov Automaton](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_6_1/core/org/apache/lucene/util/automaton/DaciukMihovAutomatonBuilder.html). But then I don't know how to use the automaton for getting which was the prefix matched or not against the string. So I have 2 complementary questions:

1. How do you use a generic `Automaton` in order to get the start and
   end characters of a match?
2. How do you force the match to happen at
   the beginning of the string?